# Retrieve user outlook display name (i.e. User name) from his email id

Tags: c#, outlook, automation

How do i retrieve user name from a given email id in outlook.

Example

smtpAddress="jack.daniels@xyz.com"

i need to get the user name like daniels,jack.

Generally we use ctrl k to retrive the display name for a given mail id. but is there a way to automate this.

I tried doing this like this

```
Outlook.Application olApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.Mailitem olMail = olApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

olMail.To=smtpAddress;
Thread.sleep(200);
username = olMail.To;

olMail.Delete();
```

This works sometimes but most of the time i end up with the email id rather than the display user name for the user.
Is there a way to achieve what i need ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call Application.Session.CreateRecipient (returns Recipient object), call Recipient.Resolve, read Recipient.Name property.